# How to write a function which takes a slice?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I would like to write a function in Python which takes a slice as a parameter. Ideally a user would be to be able to call the function as follows:

```
foo(a:b:c)
```

Unfortunately, this syntax is not permitted by Python - the use of `a:b:c` is only allowed within `[]`, not `()`.

I therefore see three possibilities for my function:

1. Require the user to use a slice "constructor" (where `s_` acts like [the version provided by numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html)):

   ```
   foo(slice(a, b, c))
   foo(s_[a:b:c])
   ```
2. Put the logic of my function into a `__getitem__` method:

   ```
   foo[a:b:c]
   ```
3. Give up trying to take a slice and take start, stop and step individually:

   ```
   foo(a, b, c)
   ```

Is there a way to get the original syntax to work? If not, which of the workaround syntaxes would be preferred? Or is there another, better option?

Comment: I would use  use start,  stop, and step setting default values

Comment: How is this primarily opinion based? This is a completely valid question.

Comment: I don't see any downside at all to using `foo(a,b,c)` rather than `foo(a:b:c)`.

Answer (score 10):

Don't surprise your users.

If you use the slicing syntax consistently with what a developer expects from a slicing syntax, that same developer will expect square brackets operation, i.e. a `__getitem__()` method.

If instead the returned object is not somehow a slice of the original object, people will be confused if you stick to a `__getitem__()` solution. Use a function call `foo(a, b, c)`, don't mention slices at all, and optionally assign default values if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Slices make more sense when they're expressed as a slice of something. So, another alternative is to be more object-oriented: create a temporary object that represents your slice of something, and put your function as a method of it.

For example, if your function is really:

```
foo(bar, a:b:c)
```

or

```
bar.foo(a:b:c)
```

then you can replace this with:

```
bar[a:b:c].foo()
```

If `bar[a:b:c]` already has a different meaning, then come up with a another name `baz` and do:

```
bar.baz[a:b:c].foo()
```

It's hard to give convincing examples without a real context, because you're trying to name related things with names that make intuitive sense, let you write unambiguous code, and are relatively short.

If you're really just writing a function on its own operating on a slice, then either:

1. Your function modifies a slice, returning a different slice:

   ```
   bar[foo(a:b:c)]
   ```

   If this is the case, whatever valid syntax you choose is going to look a little confusing. You probably don't want to use slices if you're aiming for a broad audience of Python programmers.
2. Your function really operates on *a slice of the integers*, so you can make that explicit with a temporary object:

   ```
   the_integers[a:b:c].foo()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `[a:b:c]` is, as you note, a syntax thing.  The interpreter raises a `syntax error` for `(a:b:c)` right away, before your code has any chance to do something with the values.  There isn't a way around this syntax without rewriting the interpreter.

It's worth keeping in mind that the interpreter translates `foo[a:b:c]` to

```
foo.__getitem__(slice(a,b,c))
```

The `slice` object itself is not very complicated.  It just has 3 attributes (`start`,`step`,`stop`) and a method `indices`.  It's the `getitem` method that makes sense of those values.

`np.s_` and other functions/classes in `np.lib.index_tricks` are good examples of how `__getitem__` and `slice` can be used to extend (or simplify) indexing. For example, these are equivalent:

```
np.r_[3:4:10j]
np.linspace(3,4,10)
```

As to the `foo(a,b,c)` syntax, the very common `np.arange()` uses it.  As does `range` and `xrange`. So you, and your users, should be quite familiar with it.

Since the alternatives all end up giving you the `start/step/stop` trio of values, they are functionally equivalent (in speed).  So the choice comes down to user preferences and familiarity.

While your function can't take `a:b:c` notation directly, it can be written to handle a variety of inputs - a slice, 3 positional arguments, a tuple, a tuple of slices (as from `s_`), or keyword arguments.  And following the basic `numpy` indexing you could distinguish between tuples and lists.